# Installing IParl extension

Tags: extension

I have installed the extension to work with IParl. I am at the stage in the intructions where I want to test whether the API is working.

The instructions https://github.com/artfulrobot/uk.artfulrobot.civicrm.iparl

The instructions you can test it using curl or http. Where would I actually write this script? I do have access the command line on the server but I'm not overly familiar with it yet. Would I create the script in a small file and run it from the command line?

curl -k -L 'https://yoursite.org/civicrm/iparl-webhook' 
-d secret=helloHorseHeadLikeYourJumper 
-d name=Jo 
-d surname=Bloggs 
-d email=jo@example.com 
-d actionid=1
or, with httpie

http --verify no -f POST 'https://yoursite.org/civicrm/iparl-webhook' 
secret=helloHorseHeadLikeYourJumper 
name=Jo 
lastname=Bloggs 
email=jo@example

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While these commands are split into multiple lines for readability, that curl statement is a single command.  You can paste that straight into your command line; depending on your shell, you might need to remove line breaks so it's all on a single line.

Comment: Great that worked - thanks Jon!